# Omnicompletion search suggestions

Tags: vim

Is there any way to configure Omnicompletion for `/` searches? So searching for `/be` would suggest other words in the text such as:

```
/be<tab>
```

- Beatles
- beer
- Beethoven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

personally, I think after typing `/` you can type a regex, auto-completion doesn't make much sense here... vim doesn't know what you want to have, how can it give suggestions? It is not like in Insert mode.

However there is way to achieve it.

- you type <kbd>/</kbd>
- you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>
- you type <kbd>i</kbd> (go into insert mode)
- you type <kbd>be</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

now you see the popup menu.

this works not only for <kbd>/</kbd>, but also for <kbd>:</kbd> (cmd mode)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> is handy when we write long commands

detail:

```
:h cedit
```

Comment: Thank you, this is terrific!

Comment: Vim doesn't autocomplete on `<Tab>`, either you remapped it or some plugin is doing the work. Default is `<C-N>` and `<C-P>`.

Comment: You can also start with `q/` instead of `/<C-F>` .

Comment: @glts. In fact, I do already have `Tab` mapped to complete. But `^N` and `^P` also work if I need to work on another system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [CmdlineComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222).
It will be triggered with `<C-n>` / `<C-p>`, and won't show a completion menu (but you can cycle through candidates by repeating the trigger).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`'incsearch'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27incsearch%27) and command-line completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> ([`:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W)) to achieve something quite close to what you want:

1. `:set incsearch`.
2. Start typing your search pattern, e.g. `/Be`. The cursor moves to the next potential match as you type.
3. As soon as the cursor lands on the word you want to complete, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. This pulls the word down into your search prompt: it effectively "completes" your search pattern.

At stage 3 you could also use these variants instead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> ([`:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A)) pulls down the *WORD* instead of the *word*.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> ([`:h c_CTRL-L`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-L)) completes character by character.

Answer (score 1):

I used the aforementioned CmdLineComplete plugin until I learned about

```
set incsearch
```